# Why does scala compiler allow invocation of PartialFunction without arguments?

Tags: scala, function, pattern-matching

I was kind of disappointed by the fact that scala compiler allows to compile this pretty wierd, obviously mistaken code:

```
val foo: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
  case s: String => println(s)
}
foo()
```

and instead of printing compile-error, it throws

`Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: () (of class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit)`

What was the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case your partial function takes an `Any` argument, and that includes Unit (since unit is a subtype of Any - `Any -> AnyVal -> Unit`). Calling `apply()` on that is equal to calling `apply(())`.

If you have a partial function which *doesn't* accept `Unit` you get an error indicating that the argument for apply is missing:

```
scala> val foo : PartialFunction[AnyRef, Unit] = {
     | case arg => println(s"arg = $arg")
     | }
foo: PartialFunction[AnyRef,Unit] = <function1>

scala> foo()
<console>:13: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: AnyRef)Unit in trait Function1.
Unspecified value parameter v1.
       foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

> What was the reason for that?

Because when accepting a parameter of type `Any`, the compiler deduces that type of `Unit` is applicable in that case, and thus passes the `Unit` type to `foo.apply` of the `PartialFunction`:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val foo: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = ({
    @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class $anonfun extends scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction[Any,Unit] with Serializable {
      def <init>(): <$anon: Any => Unit> = {
        $anonfun.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      final override def applyOrElse[A1, B1 >: Unit](x1: A1, default: A1 => B1): B1 = ((x1.asInstanceOf[Any]: Any): Any @unchecked) match {
        case (s @ (_: String)) => scala.this.Predef.println(s)
        case (defaultCase$ @ _) => default.apply(x1)
      };
      final def isDefinedAt(x1: Any): Boolean = ((x1.asInstanceOf[Any]: Any): Any @unchecked) match {
        case (s @ (_: String)) => true
        case (defaultCase$ @ _) => false
      }
    };
    new $anonfun()
  }: PartialFunction[Any,Unit]);
  foo.apply(())
}
```

If the type restriction was *narrower*, i.e `AnyRef`, you'd see a compiler error as `Unit` inherits `AnyVal`, and now the compiler can't provide any implicit "help".